# how to implement push notification in phonegap using ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to implement push notification in my existing ionic mobile app. if anyone knows any good references on this please share.

Thanks in @dvance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't you checked the ionic documentation? 
[Push From Scratch](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-from-scratch)